# can't use pattern matching with datatypes defined using GADT in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, typeclass, gadt

I'm trying to define a `Complex` datatype, and I want the constructors to be able to take any number as instance, so I would like to use a generic type as long as it does implement a `Num` instance

I'm usind `GADT`s in order to do so since to my understanding the `DataTypeContexts` language extension was a "*misfeature*" even if I think that would have been useful in this case...

In any case this is my code:

```hs
data Complex where
    Real            :: ( Num num, Show num ) => num -> Complex
    Imaginary       :: ( Num num, Show num ) => num -> Complex
    Complex         :: ( Num num, Show num ) => num -> num -> Complex


real :: ( Num num, Show num ) => Complex -> num
real (Real r)        = r
real (Imaginary _i ) = 0
real (Complex r _i ) = r
```

here the `real` implementation gives the following error:

```hs
Couldn't match expected type ‘num’ with actual type ‘num1’
  ‘num1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      Real :: forall num. (Num num, Show num) => num -> Complex,
    in an equation for ‘real’
    at <...>/Complex.hs:29:7-12
  ‘num’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      real :: forall num. (Num num, Show num) => Complex -> num
    at <...>/Complex.hs:28:1-47
• In the expression: r
  In an equation for ‘real’: real (Real r) = r
• Relevant bindings include
    r :: num1
      (bound at <...>/Complex.hs:29:12)
    real :: Complex -> num
      (bound at <...>/Complex.hs:29:1)
```

which to my understanding is due to the return type do be interpreted as different...
so I tried removing the type definition and letting `ghc` do his magic with the type but turns out the type signature was the same...

can anyone please explain to me what is wrong here?

Comment: so I don't know the solution, but the problem you have here isn't to do with any compiler bugs or issues. It's because you allow `Complex` to be constructed with any (showable) numeric type, and then in `real` you ask to return any numeric type - and this doesn't have to be the same one it was constructed with. That's why your definitions fundamentally don't work.

Comment: to be more concrete: you allow be to define `aComplexExample = Real 4.5`, but based on your type signature for `real` I should be able to ask for `real aComplexExample :: Int`, which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: if you just write `Complex num` instead of `Complex` everywhere (in types), it'll work, and will be equivalent to the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, these definitions allow you to choose different types when (1) constructing a `Complex` value and when (2) applying the `real` function. These two situations are not connected to each other in any way, so there is nothing to force the type to be the same between them. For example:

```hs
c :: Complex
c = Real (42 :: Int)

d :: Double
d = real c
```

The definition of `d` requires the `real` function to return a `Double`, but there is no `Double` wrapped inside of `c`, there is only `Int`.

---

As for solutions, there are two possible ones: (1) establish a connection between these two points, forcing the type to be the same, and (2) allow the type inside to be converted to any other numeric type.

**To establish a type-level connection between two points**, we need to use a type that is present at both points. What type would that be? Quite obviously, that's the type of `c`. So we need to make the type of `c` somehow convey what's wrapped inside it:

```hs
data Complex num = Real num | Imaginary num | Complex num num

real :: Complex num -> num
real = ...

-- Usage:
c :: Complex Int
c = Real 42

d :: Int
d = real c
```

Note that I don't actually need GADTs for this.

---

**To allow type conversion**, you'll need to require another type class for the `num` type. The class `Num` has a way to convert *from* any integral type, but there is no way to convert *to* any such type, because it doesn't make sense: 3.1415 can't be meaningfully converted to an integral type.

So you'll have to come up with your own way to convert, and implement it for all allowed types too:

```hs
class Convert a where
  toNum :: Num n => a -> n

data Complex where
    Real            :: ( Num num, Show num, Convert num ) => num -> Complex
    ...

real :: Num num => Complex -> num
real (Real r) = toNum r
...
```

Just to be clear, I consider the second option quite insane. I only provided it for illustration. Don't do it. Go with option 1.